# How to get onchange Javascript/jQuery functionality to run onload (doesn't work in <body onload>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/a8ZWx/274/ ...When the third select option is selected, a text-box appears.

However, if I were to load the page with the the third option already selected (insert 'selected' into the script tag, for example), the text-box doesn't appear (See: http://jsfiddle.net/a8ZWx/275/). I know this is because the select didn't necessarily make a change.

HTML code:

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="0">One</option>
<option value="1">Two</option>
<option value="2" selected>Three</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtData" style="display:none;" />
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
if($(this).val() == 2)
    $('#txtData').show();
else
    $('#txtData').hide();
});
```

My question is, how do I get the text-box to show when the select is loaded with the third option selected already. I tried inserting the function into the onload of the body tag but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try triggering the event on page load:

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
    //...
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwjxrhwo/